# Mapping with Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am new to shiny and trying to do some mapping with leaflet.I already have the map layers though in qgs format.How can I use these qgis layers  and make custom tiles(layers) for interactive mapping? Guidance on converting the qgis layers into leaflet mapping format would be appreciated.

Here is an image of the layers in QGIS:
[Map Layers in QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Y6L.png)

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add layers by using e.g. `addWMSTiles`. Here's a workable example below which add QGIS layer to interactive `leaflet` Shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(
      options = leafletOptions(
        center = c(-33.95293, 20.82824),
        zoom = 14,
        minZoom = 5,
        maxZoom = 18,
        maxBounds = list(
          c(-33.91444, 20.75351),
          c(-33.98731, 20.90626)
        )
      )
    ) %>%
      addWMSTiles(
        baseUrl = paste0(
          "http://maps.kartoza.com/web/?",
          "map=/web/Boosmansbos/Boosmansbos.qgs"
        ),
        layers = "Boosmansbos",
        options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
        attribution = paste0(
          "(c)<a href= \"http://kartoza.com\">Kartoza.com</a> and ",
          "<a href= \"http://www.ngi.gov.za/\">SA-NGI</a>"
        )
      ) %>%
      addWMSLegend(
        uri = paste0(
          "http://maps.kartoza.com/web/?",
          "map=/web/Boosmansbos/Boosmansbos.qgs&&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0",
          "&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYER=Boosmansbos&STYLE="
        )
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Shiny Leaflet App]

Comment: I was able to extract the layers from the qgis and combine with my csv data file.Thanks for the answer.